# Xcode's GDB says "Warning: the current language does not match this frame" when installing on device

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, gdb

I am building an audio-based iOS app that uses C++ libraries. Everything built and installed fine on Xcode 3 and iOS 4.

I'm working on an app that builds and runs perfectly fine on the simulator, but when installing on the device, I get the following error:

`Current language:  auto; currently objective-c++`

`Warning: the current language does not match this frame.`

There's an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in one of the C++ header files (`baseClass.h`). The file type says `Default C header`, and the implementation file (`baseClass.cpp`) has `Default - C++ source` as its file type. I tried changing the file type of the header to `C++ header`, but the problem remains.

Why does GDB say it's a language problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was initialising the Audio Session before initialising the objects active in the Audio Callback. This isn't a problem if you run the app on the Simulator, but when run on the device the Audio Callback can't find the objects that are supposed to be inside it and crashes!

So fixing this was just a matter of initialising said objects before initialising the Audio Session.

Answer (score 0):

Your c++ implementation files should be renamed to `.mm` (e.g. `baseClass.mm`). Try that and see if it works.

Comment: The implementation files are already renamed `.mm`, so I don't think that's the problem.